# codeblocks error ld||cannot find -lSDL2_image| ld||cannot find -lSDL2_mixer|

Tags: c++

i am using code-blocks mingw32 portable as my c++ compiler 
my compiler gives error while compiling the cpp(link to cpp is given below).
error is  as follows :-

```
ld||cannot find -lSDL2_image|
ld||cannot find -lSDL2_mixer|
||=== Build finished: 2 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 4 seconds) ===|
```

i had already included  -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_mixer in the linker options

link to cpp file downloaded from lazyfoo :-
 http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/06_extension_libraries_and_loading_other_image_formats/index2.php

I would really appreciate your help!!!!

Comment: You could *at least* show your compile commandline that is failing and the exact error message.

Comment: it is showing error like this   ld||cannot find -lSDL2_image|
ld||cannot find -lSDL2_mixer|
||=== Build finished: 2 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 4 seconds) ===|

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add the lib files of

```
sdl_image and sdl_mixer
```

to the minw32's lib folder as in above error compiler isn't able to find linked libraries